# How to format date in VisualForce?

Tags: java, salesforce

I am newbie to the `SalesForce` and `VisualForce` platform. I need to format the `Created Date` like the other field (in single line with space).

[image]

I developed the below code, what changes is expected in order to print the date in single line?

```
<apex:page standardController="account">
        <apex:pageBlock title="The PageBLock">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:outputField value="{!account.name}"/>  
                <apex:outputField value="{!account.billingstate}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!account.AccountNumber}"/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Name and Account Number" />
                    <apex:outputText value="{!account.name} {!account.AccountNumber}"></apex:outputText>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputText value="{0,date,long}">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Created Date" />
                        <apex:param value="{!account.CreatedDate}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.account.FieldSets.New_Set}" var="field" >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!account[field]}"/>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code that will print date in same format as above but with proper label and alignment

```
<apex:page standardController="account">
    <apex:pageBlock title="The PageBLock">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:outputField value="{!account.name}"/>  
            <apex:outputField value="{!account.billingstate}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!account.AccountNumber}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Name and Account Number" />
                <apex:outputText value="{!account.name} {!account.AccountNumber}"></apex:outputText>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Created Date" />
                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,long}">                    
                    <apex:param value="{!account.CreatedDate}"/>
                </apex:outputText>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

I hope this will work for you.